# Взаимоисключающие checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть 2 checkbox. Когда выделен один второй должен быть неактивен (`IsEnabled = false`) и наоборот. В разметке делаю так :

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Money" Content="Рrice" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Count, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

и получается наоборот - `Money` становиться активен только когда выбран второй чекбокс `Count`. Можно ли это поправить в разметке не создавая вьюмодели? Как то так `Path=!IsChecked` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) в чистом виде - вам нужен Radio Button

Comment: аплодирую вашему решению!)